# How do named paths work in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

The highlighted code in the above picture creates the named routes in the below. However, I don't understand how this setup is helpful, because if the "login_path" which is a named path variable is automatically (hidden to the user) created by "get /login" in the routes.rb file, then how do we change "login_path" to point to something else like "get /login_new_url"? I thought the whole point of the named path variables was easy posterior editing of URLs.

Comment: you can use `as` syntax,

`get '/login_new_url', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login_new_url'`

Answer (score 0):

There's a third option you can add to your routes. Learn more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code).

`get '/login_new_url', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'`

This will give you an external-facing url /login_new_url but allow you to use the `login_path` variable internally in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change path, you can try this:

```
get '/your_url', => 'controller_name#action_name', as: :your_path
```